# Execute statement/code when program runs

Tags: java, netbeans

The title is a bit confusing so I'll try to explain more in here.

I'm quite new to computer programming and have been using Netbeans for my Java programming (stop laughing) and have found out that in order to execute a statement, an event has to be fired off (such as clicking a button) but how would I make it so that when the program starts, it creates an event that I could set to fire off statements/code.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: I don't have any code to show, but I can put it in pseudocode.

```
when <Program starts>
do <lblMessage.setText("Hello World");
```

Instead of

```
when <button clicked>
do <lblMessage.setText("Hello World");
```

Comment: Show your code... (and there is nothing laughable about using Netbeans - it is a good IDE).

Comment: Show some code you have tried and we can help from there.

Comment: Well that's about it: in your main or initComponents method or whatever Netbeans calls it, just write `lblMessage.setText("Hello");` after the label has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Without any context, your described code works here

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JLabel lblMessage = new JLabel();
            lblMessage.setText("Hello, World");
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.add(lblMessage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should run it on the EDT.